# Cannot find Price in Excel Document

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of Stock prices that i have imported into Excel. I wanted to check if a given price would have potentially been reached within the range of the Open Price and the Close price of any given day.
For Example:
The Price I am looking for is 11.98
I Now want to know if within the last 100 trading days of data that I have...how many times the price of 11.98 could have appeared. With the idea that if the Open Price on a hypothetical day was 11.50 and the closing price of the same stock on that day was 12.23, then Hypothetically the price of 11.98 could have occurred). If price i am searching for (in my example, 11.98) could hypothetically have occurred in a day, I will count that as one occurrence...using my example of 100 trading days...then the maximum number of occurrences would be 100 (or once per day). I would like to do this in excel and would like help in what the formula should be. Ultimately, I would like a value representing how many times the price I am interested in has occured. THank you in advance.

Comment: Read up on the COUNTIF and COUNTIFS formulas.  You can also do this with a sum product.

Comment: How is your data layed out? can you supply a small sample of your hypothetical data?

Comment: Going to reword your question to see if I understand it right.  You want to count the number of time a price was between the opening and closing price within the past 100 days.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume column A is your date, column B is your opening price, column C is your closing price and the price you are looking for is in D2.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6>=TODAY()-100)*(B2:B6<=$D$2)*(C2:C6>=$D$2))+SUMPRODUCT((A2:A6>=TODAY()-100)*(B2:B6>=$D$2)*(C2:C6<=$D$2))
```

Now this will not cover case where the opening price and the closing price are both lower or both higher than a trading price occurring in the middle of the day.

NOTE:  This assumes that the date in column A is stored in excel time date serial format and is not text.  If it is text the formula will need to be adjusted.

Comment: Thank you Forward Ed. That Totally worked. Thank you for the fast response. Torre

Comment: Forward Ed,One more question. If I now want to expand my search for the price I am looking for greater than Row 6, do I simply change the number from 6 to say 156 assuming that i have that many rows of data? And lastly, if I want to check multiple number without needing to type in each one into D2..is there a way of copying the formula you wrote down an entire column(for example currently i have your formula in column E) and then copy and pasting the prices I am looking for into the rows corresponding formula within column D?

Comment: for expanding your range you need to increase the number 6 to whatever the last row is.  That applies to A6 B6 an C6.

Comment: You can also copy this down, but you are going to want to learn about locking address as I like to refer to it as (not sure what the technical term is).  You need to learn about how the $ affects cell address references.  Go to an empty cell somewhere and type in =A1 and then copy it watch what happens to the address in the copied cells.  Now try that again with =$A$1 and again with =A$1 and again with =$A1.  notice what is happening when you copy.  And the trick I was so happy about and it only took me 4 years to learn.  Place your cursor next to or within an address and press F4 repeatedly.